# AdMob Interstitial Ad never becoming "ready"

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm using **Xcode 7.3, Swift, SpriteKit, and AdMob**. I'm attempting to display an **Interstitial** ad, but no matter how long I wait the request is never filled and `self.interstitial.isReady` always is false. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let request = GADRequest()
        // Requests test ads on test devices.
        request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
        self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        }
    func displayAd() {
        print(self.interstitial.isReady)
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }
    }
}
```

In another swift file I'm calling `GameViewController().displayAd()`. This always prints false since interstitial.isReady is never true. *A possible problem - I might be using the wrong test adUnitId or the request.testDevices is not being set to the correct thing.

Why is it that this request wont fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those reading this at a later time I fixed it, there were two problems:

I'm not using an actualy Ad, so `request.testDevices` should not be set to anything

Additionally, when I call `GameViewController().displayAd()`, I'm making a new instance of `GameViewController`, and it has to be the original. To avoid this I made a variable that referenced `GameViewController's` self, then did 
`variable.displayAd()`